# Archive for custom taxonomy lists all posts instead of current taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, plugin-types

I'm using the Types plugin for a custom post type "Session", which has the custom taxonomy "Semester". I would now like to create an archive page for each semester which is automatically generated. Creating a taxonomy-semester.php was no problem, however, that page always shows contents for ALL semesters, not just the current one the URL points to.

E.g. /semester/winter2015 and /semester/summer2016 will both show contents for Winter 2015 (or whatever is in the database). I'm pretty sure the problem lies within my query arguments, but no matter what I try, I can't get this page to show only the contents for the correct semester. Here's my code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="index-post-list">     

<?php 

$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
$getterm = $term->slug; // get current slug (E.g. winter2015)

    $args = (array(
    'post_type' => 'session', 
    'tax_query' => array(                     
        'taxonomy' => 'semester',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $getterm,
        'include_children' => true,          
        'operator' => 'IN' 
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-start-time', // custom post field by which results are sorted
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    ) );  

    $query = new wp_query( $args );

        <h2 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'Schedule for %s', 'template' ), single_tag_title( '', false ) ); ?></h2>
        <?php echo tag_description(); ?>


        <?php if ( $query -> have_posts() ) : while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post(); ?>


    //usual loop stuff goes here....



    <?php endif; ?>



</section><!--index-post-list-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't create a new query to modify query arguments, use `pre_get_posts` and modify the main query before it's run and eliminate the new query in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your query. According to the [documentation for WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), `tax_query` is an *array of arrays of parameters*, which is to say that it should probably look like this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(                     
        'taxonomy' => 'semester',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $getterm,
        'include_children' => true,          
        'operator' => 'IN' 
    ),
),
```